# How can I change data on parent class from child class on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, parent-child

I want to access and change data on parent class from child class. For this when I do it as in the code example below, it works. However, when I import the child class (ChildPage) from outside, not inside the same dart file, I cannot access the _MainPageState class.

It works like this.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ChildPage(this),
      ],
    );
  }
}

//this is my child page
class ChildPage extends StatefulWidget {
  _MainPageState parent;
  ChildPage(this.parent);

  @override
  _ChildPageState createState() => _ChildPageState();
}

class _ChildPageState extends State<ChildPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          widget.parent.setState(() {
            widget.parent.selectedIndex = 1;
          });
        },
        child: Text('click'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It works when I write the above way. However, I want to separate both classes and write them as different dart files. For this, I tried to do as follows, but was not successful. I want to change the selectedIndex variable in main.dart by accessing it from the child.dart file. How can I do it?

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ChildPage(this),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**child.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class ChildPage extends StatefulWidget {
  _MainPageState parent; // it shows Undefined class '_MainPageState'.
  ChildPage(this.parent);

  @override
  _ChildPageState createState() => _ChildPageState();
}

class _ChildPageState extends State<ChildPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          // here i want to access selectedIndex in main.dart like widget.parent.selectedIndex
        },
        child: Text('click'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to do like [tab controller](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html).

Or you can use like below with Navigator.

**1- Navigation Helper**

```
class NavigationHelper{
  static const String HOME="/home";
  static const String DETAIL="/detail";
}
```

**2- Main**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter sadas',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        routes: {
          "/home": (context) => MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo asdad Page'),
          "/firebase": (context) => FireBaseBook(),
          "/pageview": (context) => PageViewM(),
          "/html": (context) => HTML(),
          "/file": (context) => FileDown(),
          "/tab": (context) => MyTabBar(),
          "/sliver": (context) => SliverView(),
          "/detail": (context) => Detail(),
          "/": (context) => DownloadWidget(),
        });
  }
}
```

**3- Navigator**

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, NavigationHelper.DETAIL);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mevlüt Gür. It is really proud to see Turkish developers around here. Unfortunately, this is not the answer that I was looking for. I want to use bottomNavigationBar , not tab controller So, when I use Routes the bottomNavigationBar is not fixed. I want to fixed it every page.